# Angular, set ui-view inside ui-view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a question about multiple views. It's difficult to explain but I'll try:

Navigating to state 'About' and setting template url for ui-view 'columnOne' and ui-view 'columnTwo' was done succesfully

```
    .state('about', {
    url: '/about',
    views: {

        // the main template will be placed here (relatively named)
        '': { templateUrl: 'partial-about.html' },

        // the child views will be defined here (absolutely named)
        'columnOne@about': { template: 'Look I am a column!' },

        // for column two, we'll define a separate controller 
        'columnTwo@about': { 
            templateUrl: 'table-data.html',
            controller: 'scotchController'
        }
    }

});
```

Now I would like to set the templateUrl of view 'columTwo' from view 'columnOne'.
How is this done? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The example your taking from there website is parallel view example not nested view nested view can be made by making a page and than making other states with . like registration is a page and multistep form than the page containing registration uiview will we state registration and the parts with be like registration.contact,registration.acadamics, registration.extraactivities. And really man there documentation is quiet confusing

Comment: Do you have an example?